# Очистка результатов компиляции от стандартных библиотек

Tags: c#

В какой-то момент в результатах компиляции стали появляться стандартные библиотеки, то-есть, например в `bin/Debug/` появились такие файлы как:

- System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
- System.Collections.dll
- System.Data.Common.dll
- System.IO.dll
- System.Threading.dll

И им подобные файлы стандартных библиотек. 
Сравнив состояние репозитория от момента, когда такого не происходило я не обнаружил ничего что-бы могло вызвать такой эффект. Почему такое может происходить?

---

P.S. Проект использует .net Framowork 4.6.1

Comment: Какой-то из nuget-пакетов это требует. Обновляли пакеты?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, обновлял. Сейчас пойду проверять. Есть какой-нибудь стандартный способ отключения?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, действительно. Добавил 2 пакета, а они подтянули за собой уже все зависимости. Из способов очистки, на сколько я понимаю, только какой-нибудь *Costura.Fody* (ну кроме удаления этих пакетов)?

Comment: Судя по всему надо открывать issue и просить автора пакета пофиксить это, вот пример подобной ситуации: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5871 https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/issues/650 https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/issues/638

Comment: @АндрейNOP хорошо, открою issue. Оформите как ответ сами, или я?

Comment: Я не буду, можете сами написать, если вопрос решен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правильно подсказал Андрей NOP в комментариях - проблема была в том, что я установил себе в проект новый nuget-пакет, и не посмотрел на зависимости.

Варианты исправления:

- Удалить этот пакет
- Написать автору, что у него проблемы с библиотеками
- Использовать `Costura.Fody`